# Can I unscrew screws from anchors mounted in stucco and then be able to rescrew into the same anchors?

Tags: stucco

I have a bracket mounted on a stucco wall that I want to take off temporarily. The bracket was mounted into the stucco with green plastic anchors. Can I unscrew the screws from the anchors without damaging them? I want to rehang the bracket in the same spot using the same anchors.

Comment: how do know that the anchors are in good condition? ... what is preventing you from replacing the anchors?

Comment: I am with @jsotola, being plastic, and depending on the age they could have become brittle.

Comment: It probably won't be stronger with the old anchors. If you're mounting a shelf filled with priceless Fabergé  eggs and Ming Dynasty vases..

Answer (score 0):

As you know the anchors get deformed during the process if they are plastic.

How much ? that depends.

Unscrewing the screw and trying to screw it back in will be a matter of luck.

Mostly it will work if you manage to screw it in without creating new tread in the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, yes. But if something goes awry, you can always pull the old anchor out and use a new one, perhaps one of a slightly larger size to compensate for any crumbling of the stucco.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a shot.

If the screw feels loose in the anchor, use a larger size screw (same length, larger diameter) to get a better bite in the plastic anchor.